# vector calculus divergence theorem problem

Tags: vector-analysis

If one let $\psi(x,y,z)$ be a scalar field defined within a volume V be bounded by a simple closed surface S how would they go about proving, would it be easier to start with the rhs or the lhs? i assume i would need to use the divergence theorem?

$\iint_S\psi\nabla\psi.\bar{n}dS$=$\iiint_V(\psi\nabla^2\psi+(\nabla\psi)^2dV$

my attempt is as follows

Let $F=\psi\nabla\psi$ then $\nabla.F=\nabla.(\psi\nabla\psi)=\psi\nabla.\nabla\psi+\nabla\psi.\nabla\psi$ by the product rule.

so $\iiint_v \psi\nabla.\nabla\psi+\nabla\psi.\nabla\psi  dV=\iiint_v\psi\nabla^2\psi+(\nabla\psi)^2dV$ since $\nabla.\nabla=\nabla^2$ and thus $\nabla\psi.\nabla\psi=(\nabla\psi)^2$  from identities ?

Comment: Yes, use the divergence theorem. Calculate $\nabla(\psi\nabla\psi)$

Comment: we would take $F=\psi\nabla\psi$?

Comment: You have the gradient of such product proved in many places, but maybe is a nice exercise try to do it by yourself. Apply the definition of divergence to $\psi$ and its gradient. Partial derivatives are not as hard as it seems at first.

Comment: okay thank you, i will try this now and post my working as an edit

Comment: updated post can you see if it is correct?

Comment: I was referring to prove the chain rule, but it depends on how deep you need to go.

Comment: we dont need to prove the chain rule in this course seems more relevant to real analysis , its been given to us in lectures,

Comment: So, it's done :)

Comment: Brilliant, are cartesian tensors useful with vector calc, because its in the course text however they don't teach it anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

From product rule differentiation, we have $$\nabla \cdot\left( \phi(\vec r)\vec A(\vec r)\right)=\phi(\vec r)\nabla \cdot \vec A(\vec r)+\vec A(\vec r)\cdot \nabla \phi(\vec r)$$

Now, let $\phi=\psi$ and $\vec A=\nabla \psi$ in the Divergence Theorem.

Comment: is my working correct and sufficient for  a proof?

Comment: Yes.  Just one last part.  $$\int_V \nabla \cdot (\psi \nabla \psi)\,dV=\oint_S \psi \nabla \psi \,\cdot \hat n\,dS$$

Comment: ah okay thank you an extended part of the question is to set $\psi=x+y+z$ it wants you to find the value of $\iint_s \psi\nabla\psi.\hat ndS$ my question is where do we generate the upper and lower limits for the integral to find a numerical solution?

Comment: Note that if $\psi =x+y+z$, then $ \nabla^2 \psi=0$ and $|\nabla \psi|^2=3$.  Hence, $\oint \psi \nabla \psi \cdot \hat n\,dS=3V$.

Comment: do need to calculate n? which is just $\frac{\nabla\psi}{|\nabla\psi|}$?

Comment: Hi could you put the part we discussed in your answer to clarify , thanks

Comment: The unit vector $\hat n$ to the surface $S$ is not related whatsoever  to the normal vector to the level surfaces given by $\psi=\text{constant}$.

Comment: okay, i'm getting confused can you solve it in your answer, never seen one like this before where there haven't been given conditions on x,y,z, Thanks

Comment: What problem do you mean?  If you mean the one for which $\psi=x+y+z$, then I've provided the answer in a previous comment.  The answer is $3V$, where$ V$ is the volume enclosed by $S$.

Comment: i dont understand why we take the modulus where does that fit in, originally i thought it was because we needed to calculate n but that isnt the case ?

Comment: We use the relationship in the OP that we proved in my answer.

Comment: okay i made a new post here explaining my difficulties http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170581/divergence-theorem-problem-find-volume-in-terms-of-v

Answer (score 0):

From my best guess (nabla Phi)^2 means the modulus squared. surely since nabla phi is a vector, you can't square a vector. it must mean modulus.

Comment: by squared we mean $$\nabla \phi . \nabla \phi=(\nabla \phi)^2=|\nabla \phi|^2$$

Comment: no way.
Dot product being represented by being squared is not real notation, i'm certain of that. in spiegel it uses two different scalars and it ends up with dot product

Comment: By definition $$\nabla . \nabla = \nabla ^2$$

Comment: It's a basic result to prove try with a general $$\psi$$