# Divergence theorem problem find volume in terms of V

Tags: vector-analysis

Let $\psi=x+y+z$ then find the value of

$\iint_S \psi\nabla\psi.\hat n dS$ i know the answer is $3V$

My attempt

we know that $\iint_S \psi\nabla\psi.\hat n dS=\iiint_V (\psi \nabla^2\psi+(\nabla\psi)^2dV$ From the divergence theorem, and clearly $\nabla^2\psi=0$ so we have $\iiint_V(\nabla\psi)^2dV$ but then i dont know where to go from here. i know that $|\nabla\psi|^2=3$ but i dont understand how that fits in here, how can one just convert the $(\nabla\psi)^2$ to $\|\nabla\psi|^2$

thanks for taking time to read this, any help would be greatly appreciated, note this problem is different than the ones i am used to attempt since there are no upper or lower bounds on the integrals.

Comment: $(\nabla \psi)^2$ and $| \nabla \psi |^2$ are the same thing. By definition, they are both equal to $\nabla \psi . \nabla \psi$, where $.$ is the dot product.

Comment: oh okay so there both equal to 3?

Comment: Also $\int\int\int_V 1 dV$ is simply the volume of the region $V$. You don't need to calculate - this should be obvious!

Comment: why is it 1? i thought it would be $\iiint_V 3dV$

Comment: It is $\int \int \int_V 3 dV$. And this equals $3V$ for the reason I just gave.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification makes perfect sense now.

Comment: You can use double $ around to get larger centered formula with no text nearby which could make it easier to read especially the longer expressions with no distracting text around.

Comment: @KennyWong may i ask how they are the same thing, for further understanding

Comment: $\iiint 1 dV$ can be intuitively thought of as $\sum 1 \delta V$, where the $\delta V$ are infinitesimal volumes of tiny little cubes that fill up your region. Clearly this is the same as the total volume of the region!

Comment: i was reffering to $$(\nabla\psi)^2 and |\nabla\psi|^2$$ why are they the same thing?